# Can you trigger a function to run in google apps script if the keyboard hasn't been pressed in a set amount of time?

Tags: google-apps-script, keyboard

Preface: I am very new to programming. I am trying to make a google docs add-on that essentially records audio when the user hasn't been typing for some time (this is to allow the audio to be converted to speech later, its a "note taking helper" add on). Sorry if I am being vague, but I do not have much done on the project so I don't really have any code to show. If there is a way to do this using google apps script that would be preferable (ie javascript/html). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Apps Script executes on a remote server, not in the user's browser.  You might be able to create some client side js that does something similar though.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, autohotkey is probably a better way to go. you could simply have a timer going that reset every time the user hit spacebar and after it hits 100 seconds it starts a recording app going.